# Craft CMS on Host Inmotion

Tags: installation

Had absolutely no issue with an older version of their host on the installation and running a Craft CMS site.

This one has been a bear

Is there a step by step on best way to install

The only real difference I see is MariaDB, yet they assured me it was just a top layer of MySQL

cPanel Version  66.0 (build 23)
Apache Version  2.4.27
PHP Version 5.6.31
MySQL Version   10.2.9-MariaDB
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the specific issues you're running into?

Comment: Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in ...

Comment: Tested this on an Older version of their hosting a client had, and it worked fine. So purchased their new VPS 2000 Hosting and trouble since

Comment: MariaDB is not a layer on top of MySQL; it's a 100% compatible drop-in replacement for MySQL, from the same forked code base, by the original author of MySQL. Craft CMS 2 & 3 both work perfectly with MariaDB, so it's likely something else. In any event, here's my suggestions for hosting: https://nystudio107.com/blog/web-hosting-for-agencies-freelancers

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in

This is usually one of 3 things:

1. The path to the `craft` folder defined in your public index.php file in `$craftPath` is incorrect.
2. The path defined in `$craftPath` is correct, but PHP doesn't have permissions to go into that folder and open index.php.
3. Your php.ini file has [open_basedir](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions in place that prevent PHP from opening that folder.

Comment: It was the second. Thanks Brad! up up and away we go by the grace of this great forum!